# Java SSL Problem - Unparseable CRLDistributionPoints extension

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, sslhandshakeexception

Java Version: 1.8.0_221

I am trying to connect to a HTTPS webservice - but the SSL handshake fails with error:

> Unparseable certificate extensions: 1 [1](https://www.quickfixj.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-fullcontent/temp/searchrequest.html?pid=10000&sorter/field=issuekey&sorter/order=desc&tempmax=1000): ObjectId: 2.5.29.31
>   Criticality=false Unparseable CRLDistributionPoints extension due to
>   java.io.IOException: invalid URI
>   name:ldap://Enroll.visaca.com:389/cn=Visa Information Delivery
>   External CA,c=US,ou=Visa International Service
>   Association,o=VISA?certificateRevocationList

On browsing the issue, not much information is shared.

Only suggestion I have is "certificate needs to be generated with enabled "Key Encipherment" suggested in this [thread](https://www.quickfixj.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-fullcontent/temp/searchrequest.html?pid=10000&sorter/field=issuekey&sorter/order=desc&tempmax=1000).

This issue is easily reproducible with command

```
keytool -list -keystore C:\cert\MyTrustStore.p12 -v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception turned out to be a false alarm. Since the ldap is internal to the third party service, my server is unable to connect to it.

The actual issue was elsewhere as the SSL certificate was accepted by server even with this exception.